# How to launch an AMI instance copied from another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, packer

Using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) I create AMI in North Virginia(us-east-1). Below is the builder snippet for it.

```
"builders": [{
"type": "amazon-ebs",
"access_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"secret_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"region": "us-east-1",
"source_ami": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"instance_type": "m4.2xlarge",
"ssh_username": "ubuntu",
"ami_users": [
"XXXXXXXXXXXX",
"YYYYYYYYYYYY"
],
"ami_name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"launch_block_device_mappings": [{
    "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
    "volume_type": "gp2",
    "delete_on_termination": true,
    "volume_size": 30
    }]
}]
```

I have no problems in launching this AMI in us-east-1. But when I copy it to Mumbai(ap-south-1) and try to launch it

> The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported. Please see the AWS Marketplace site for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems.

Most of the settings are left as default so not sure what is causing this issue. Any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: What's the source AMI and which instance type do you try to launch in `ap-south-1`?

Comment: @RickardvonEssen The source AMI is an old marketplace AMI of Ubuntu. It seems like that may be the reason. We are trying with a new ami. Will let you know the result.

Comment: Marketplace AMI cannot be moved between accounts due to license restrictions.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran It was indeed the case of Marketplace AMI being copied. If you can answer this, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marketplace AMI cannot be moved between accounts due to license restrictions

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html

> You can't copy an AMI with an associated billingProduct code that was
>   shared with you from another account. This includes Windows AMIs and
>   AMIs from the AWS Marketplace. To copy a shared AMI with a
>   billingProduct code, launch an EC2 instance in your account using the
>   shared AMI and then create an AMI from the instance. For more
>   information, see Creating an Amazon EBS-Backed Linux AMI.